# Webform 4.10 Does Not Support 'Excel' Format

Tags: 7, webforms

I recently installed ([Webform 7.x-4.10](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/releases/7.x-4.10)) to my Drupal site. It works fine but it doesn't have Microsoft Excel as Export format. The only option available is Delimited text (*.tsv), & it doesn't fit my requirements. So, I need back the MS Excel format.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: i need back the MS Excel format!

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You know excel will happily open tab separated files right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because it's not a question but feature request, and requests like that belongs to issue queue, not here.